# Quantlib Mac OSX - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: python, arm, clang, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I want to install Quantlib from source to enable intraday support for Python. When installing QuantLib from source on Mac OSX 11.1 with M1 chip I am facing a problem during the 'make' in the tests.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_PrimitivePolynomials", referenced from:
      LowDiscrepancyTest::testPolynomialsModuloTwo() in lowdiscrepancysequences.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [quantlib-test-suite] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You might get more traction on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the linker is not finding the QuantLib libraries you have just compiled, and is instead trying to link to a version compiled for a different architecture. Try running `make install` or `sudo make install` prior to compiling the tests -- if that works, then you have something going on with your library paths.